# sql server 2008: setting up a username properly in order to connect from VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, vba

i set up a login (reviewer) under security for SQL SERVER

and under the specific database i set up a User (qcvalues_reviewer) that references this login

i have tried all these different ways to login into the database from vba:

```
 'cn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=hermes;Initial Catalog=test;User ID=qcvalues_reviewer; Password=92127; Trusted_Connection=yes"

 'cn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=hermes;Database=test;User Id=qcvalues_reviewer;Password=92127;"

 'cn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=hermes;Initial Catalog=test;User Id=qcvalues_reviewer;Password=92127;"

 'cn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=10.20.10.18,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=test;User ID=qcvalues_reviewer;Password=92127;"
```

each time i get the error message:

```
login failed for user
```

can someone please help me connect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>As @GSerg points out you should log in with the `LOGIN` and not the `USER`, I read that wrong.</strike>

<strike>cn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=hermes;Initial Catalog=test;User Id=reviewer;Password=92127;"</strike>

As a stab in the dark - are you using SQL Express and if so have to enabled remote connections?

Incorrect Password

Comment: using sql server manamgen studio, how do i enable remote connections?

Comment: Management studio is a tool you use to connect to SQL server, I mean the `edition` of SQL Server you are using, you can find this out with `SELECT @@VERSION`. Here is a how to if you are using that edition http://www.linglom.com/2009/03/28/enable-remote-connection-on-sql-server-2008-express/

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   Apr  2 2010 15:48:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: As @GSerg points out you should log in with the LOGIN and not the USER, I read that wrong. - im sorry i dont understand can you write that for me

Comment: That's standard edition - it will have remote connections enabled by default - your problem will be the `User Id` see @GSerg's post.

Comment: thank you guys, i have tried the new string that chris provided and it still says bad login

Comment: should the initial catalog be the database which i want to see?

Comment: login failed for user reviewer

Comment: In the SQL error log see if it has a message about the failed login and it should give you a `state` code

Comment: 2010-08-19 11:28:33.25 Logon       Login failed for user 'reviewer'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 10.0.0.204]
2010-08-19 11:29:04.84 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
2010-08-19 11:29:04.84 Logon       Login failed for user 'reviewer'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 10.0.0.204]
2010-08-19 11:31:27.80 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
2010-08-19 11:31:27.80 Logon       Login failed for user 'reviewer'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 10.0.0.204]

Comment: There is your answer - the password is incorrect. Reset the password on the login - or change it in the connection string if there is a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the login (reviewer), not the user name (qcvalues_reviewer).

Also try using the second and the third parameters of `Connection.Open` for User and Login, respectively.

Comment: im sorry i dont understand what you mean?

Comment: You're trying to have User ID and password in the connection string, and I'm saying, try the parameters of the Open method for that. In either case, you should be using the login name, not the user name.

Comment: thank you guys, i have tried the new string that chris provided and it still says bad login

Comment: cn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=hermes;Initial Catalog=test", "reviewer", "92127"

Comment: invlaid authroization sepcification

Comment: Have you enabled mixed mode authorization on the server, or is it only willing to accept trusted connections?

Comment: By [using Google](http://www.google.com/#source=hp&q=mixed+mode+authentication&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=1&cad=b), specifically, [the first link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx) it provides?